# Delphi: check driver signature enforcement

Tags: delphi, driver, digital-signature

How to know is driver signature enforcement enabled or disabled in Windows Vista, 7?
It can be disabled using a special software or using F8 on a system startup.

It's very interesting.

Comment: In general you probably can't reliably detect this because the various software that bypass the policy do so, by necessity, with nefarious means.

Comment: That it is difficult to do because of those software

Comment: Are you targeting 32bit, 64bit or both?

Answer (score 1):

The mode where signature enforcement is off is called Test Mode. Many tools for disabling enforcement rely on switching into this mode somehow. The current state is displayed by bcdedit.exe when run from an elevated command prompt (right click on cmd.exe -> run as admin). It displays multiple settings one of them being "testsigning" with a value of "No" or "Yes". So the cheap way of detecting it from Delphi would be to run the bcdedit.exe, parse the output and look for this "testsigning" value.